# python: how to add one search path

Tags: python

I have a fold like:

```
path 
  -subpath1
  -subpath2
```

Currently, the `os.path.exists('./path')` and `os.path.exists('./path/subpath1')` would return true, and `os.path.exists('./subpath1')` return false.
Then, I want to add `'./path'` to the search path by:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('./path')
```

However, the `os.path.exists('./subpath1')` still return false. How can I add './path' to the search path?

---

update:
Sorry for not clearing for my question.
I understand that os.path.exists() would return true for os.path.join('path', 'subpath1'). However, I don't want to use os.path.join function. Actually, the 'path' is a module, and I want to load the -subfile in the code, just like:

```
path
  -subfile
  -code
```

Thus, in the 'code' file, I don't want to join the './path'.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? ``sys.path`` is the *module* search path, used by ``import``. It is not the *current working directory*, from which relative paths such as ``./subpath1`` are looked up.

Comment: Are you asking how to resolve a path relative to the current module's file?

Comment: sys.path is the module search path, is there any method to add the file search path?

Comment: There is no such thing as a file search path. There is only the so-called "current working directory" (cwd). You can change the cwd, but you cannot have multiple cwds.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this?

```
path = os.path.join("path")
or
path = os.path.join("path","subpath1")
or
path = os.path.join(".","path","subpath1")

 ## and or ##
filepath = os.path.normpath('./subpath1').
or 
filepath = os.path.normpath('./path/subpath1').
```

Answer (score 0):

I used an easy way :

```
import os
path = './path' + '/subpath1'
os.path.exists(path)  # Output : True
```

Answer (score 0):

whenever you start your path with './dir' you are using relative path, python interprets it relative to current working directly adding the path to **sys.path** with **sys.path.insert(path)** doesn't change the current working directly, for that you have to use **os.chdir(subdirpath)**.